# PHP rename file during ftp download

Tags: php, ftp

So a PHP program I built to download files from one server and upload them to another is now needed to rename the files.

For some reason I'm getting a 'invalid argument' warning on the `rename()` function which seems impossible because the file exists and there is 0 white space.

So now I was wondering if it was possible to rename a file as I download it from an ftp using `ftp_get()`?

Comment: Why not just use `ftp_fget()` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Would suggest so. Give it a local file name.

Also make sure you are using rename() correctly
http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: My gosh. I just spent 3 hours on this, totally having a brain fart that the ':' character is not allowed in a file name and that's why it kept failing. Thanks for the replies guys!